# Heap Occupancy threshold in Android

Tags: android, garbage-collection

Is it the same threshold (Heap Size) that varies from one device to another and is there any way to set this value in our app other than using largeHeap=true?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Is it the same threshold (Heap Size) that varies from one device to another`

No

`is there any way to set this value in our app other than using largeHeap=true?`

No.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. Do you know how to set this threshold value in our app programmatically?

Comment: You can't. You can get the value with getMemoryClass() or getLargeMemoryClass() though, look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html